# Map class in typescript giving an error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am getting an error saying "cannot find name Map" in typescript .

```
var myMap = new Map();

var keyString = "a string",
    keyObj = {},
    keyFunc = function () {};

// setting the values
myMap.set(keyString, "value associated with 'a string'");
myMap.set(keyObj, "value associated with keyObj");
myMap.set(keyFunc, "value associated with keyFunc");

myMap.size; // 3

// getting the values
myMap.get(keyString);    // "value associated with 'a string'"
myMap.get(keyObj);       // "value associated with keyObj"
myMap.get(keyFunc);      // "value associated with keyFunc"

myMap.get("a string");   // "value associated with 'a string'"
                         // because keyString === 'a string'
myMap.get({});           // undefined, because keyObj !== {}
myMap.get(function() {}) // undefined, because keyFunc !== function () {}
```

I dont understand why it is not considering it

moreover we have `Map` in javascript

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Map` is part of **ES6**, so you need to "target" **ES6** in order this to work.

---

In **TypeScript 2** you can keep targeting **ES5** and include required apis with *lib* option:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es5", "es2015.collection"]
}
```

More info [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#including-built-in-type-declarations-with---lib).

Comment: what do you mean by target ES6 .
could you please explain it briefly

Comment: if you're using _tsconfig.json_ - put `"target": "es6"` in `"compilerOptions"`